# Dynamically creating select2 tags inside sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm struggling to create Select2 tags inside a SweetAlert. Not too sure what I'm doing wrong but currently the created option is `'+value+'`

Am I not calling the function at the right place?

I added onRender but still no luck. Same thing.
Updated onRender:

```
  Swal.fire({

    title: '<strong>DIOR</strong>',
    icon: 'info',
    html:
      'Change tags:<br /> <br />' +
      '<select class="form-control select2 select2-multiple selectTags" id="selectTags" multiple="multiple"><option>Zero tag</option>' +
      function () {
        $.each(tags[0], function (index, value) {
          // var mySelect = $("#selectTags").append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
          // mySelect.trigger("change");

          console.log("html: " + value);
          //$("#selectTags").select2('data', { id: index, text: value });
        })
      },
    showCloseButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    focusConfirm: false,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    confirmButtonText:
      '<div class="d-flex align-items-center saveTags" id="saveTags"> <i class="dripicons-checkmark mr-2" style = "font-size: 20px" ></i > Save tags!</div > ',

    cancelButtonText:
      '<div class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="dripicons-cross mr-2" style="font-size: 20px"></i> Cancel</div>',
    cancelButtonAriaLabel: 'Thumbs down',
    onRender: function () {
      $.each(tags[0], function (index, value) {
        var mySelect = $("#selectTags").append('<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>');
        mySelect.trigger("change");

        console.log("onRender: " + value);
        $("#selectTags").select2('data', { id: index, text: value });
      })
    },
    onOpen: function () { $("#selectTags").select2({ tags: true }); console.log($("#selectTags").val()); }
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      console.log("onOpen: " + $("#selectTags").val());
      selected = $("#selectTags").val(); // array of selected tags
      //storing tags code below
      //
      /////////////////////////
      Swal.fire(
        'Saved!',
        'Selected tags were stored in the database.',
        'success'
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: i just checked the docs and it looks like you would have to move the "each-function" from html-property to the `onRender` property

Comment: @johnSmith hey John, I just added onRender but it seems like it does the same thing.

Comment: I edited the code above.

Comment: there is no code where you define `tags` , what error do you get in console, does your logs get logged?

Comment: @johnSmith sorry, tags is just a dummy array to use:

Comment: tags = [['first', 'second'], ['third', 'fourth']];

Comment: And no, I don't get any errors.